# "com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: forex-service"

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I am new to microservices and just trying to create two microservices and register them to eureka. I am getting the below exception :

```
"com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: forex-service".  Below is my configuration.
```

> **The eureka naming server class :**

`@SpringBootApplication
 @EnableEurekaServer
 public class MicroserviceEurekaNamingServerApplication {}`

**application.properties**

`spring.application.name=netflix-eureka-naming-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false`

> **Forex Service class:**

`@SpringBootApplication
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 @EnableEurekaClient
 public class Forex2Microservice2Application {}`

**application.properties**

`spring.application.name=forex-service
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka`

> **Currency Service class:**

`@SpringBootApplication
 @EnableFeignClients
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 @EnableEurekaClient
 public class SpringBootMicroserviceCurrencyConversionApplication {}`

**application.properties**

`spring.application.name=currency-conversion-service
server.port=8100
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka`

> **Feign Client**

`@FeignClient(name = "forex-service")
@RibbonClient(name = "forex-service")
public interface CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy {}`

Thanks in advance.